# Show that a potential flow must satisfy Euler's Equations

Tags: vector-analysis, classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics

I am trying to show that a potential flow must satisfy the incompressible Euler's equation:
\begin{align}
\rho \partial_t v + \rho (v \cdot \nabla ) v = - \nabla p
\end{align}

As the flow is steady we have the following:
\begin{align}
\rho\partial_t\nu +\rho(\nu\cdot \nabla)\nu= \rho\cdot 0+\rho\nu\cdot \nabla\nu 
\end{align}

I believe that $\nabla\nu$ is the covariant derivative of $\nu$? Assuming that $p$ is the dynamic pressure and is hence equal to $- \frac{\rho}{2} |v|^2$, then I must show that $\rho\nu\cdot \nabla\nu = -\nabla(- \frac{\rho}{2} |v|^2)$.

Comment: No, nabla is here the gradient operator ${\rm e_i}\partial_{x_i}$ in the sense of vector calculus, not differential geometry on manifolds, so that 
$$
(v·∇)v=v_i\,\frac{∂v_j}{∂x_i}\,{\rm e_j}
$$
As the basis vector field ${\rm e_i}$ is constant, there is no derivative of it to compensate for.

Comment: May i then use the following identity? $({\bf u}\cdot\nabla){\bf u}=
\frac{1}{2}\nabla(|{\bf u}|^2)
-{\bf u}\times(\nabla\times{\bf u}).$ I am also unsure why this equation doesnt include a gravity term on the right hand side, as I have seen in many other examples? How would I go about adjusting this proof if gravity is accounted for? Thank you.

Comment: That looks correct, \begin{align}
a·(u×(∇×u))&=\det(a,u,∇×u)=(a×u)·(∇×u)
\\&=(a·e_i)(u·∂_iu)-(a·∂_iu)(u·e_i) = a·\tfrac12∇(|u|^2)-a·(u·∇)u.
\end{align} Perhaps this is about a horizontal flow, or a shallow fast flow where gravity is a secondary concern? What is $p$, if it is a potential function and not pressure, gravity can be included in that.